# Reference Column Name with Spaces

Tags: python, pandas

Beginner question: I am trying to use the following line of code but am getting syntax errors:

```
db = db.drop('Aggregated Alliance Products', axis=1).join(db.Aggregated Alliance Products.str.split(', ', expand=True).stack().to_frame('Aggregated Alliance Products').reset_index(1, drop=True))
```

When I use `db.Aggregated Alliance Products.str.split(', ', expand=True)`, how do I adjust the column name Aggregated Alliance Products to accomodate the spaces in it?

Sample:

| A | B | Aggregated Alliance Products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | "1,2,4" |
| 3 | 4 | "5,6" |

Desired Output:

| A | B | Aggregated Alliance Products |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 6 |

Comment: try this `db['Aggregated Alliance Products']`

Comment: KeyError: "['Aggregated Alliance Products'] not found in axis"

Comment: you dropped 'Aggregated Alliance Products' at the very first..?

Comment: This is what I changed it to: db = db.drop('Aggregated Alliance Products', axis=1).join(db['Aggregated Alliance Products'].str.split(', ', expand=True).stack().to_frame('Aggregated Alliance Products').reset_index(1, drop=True))

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Edit complete to add sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

or you can use `assign` to acheive your goal without modifying original data as follows:

[image]

```py
db.assign(**{'Aggregated Alliance Products': db['Aggregated Alliance Products'].str.split(',')}).explode('Aggregated Alliance Products')
```

---

if you can modify db itself, you can use `explode` func like as follows:

```
db = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, '1,2,4'), (3, 4, '5,6')], columns=['A', 'B', 'Aggregated Alliance Products'])
db['Aggregated Alliance Products'] = db['Aggregated Alliance Products'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
db.explode('Aggregated Alliance Products')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
k=db['Aggregated Alliance Products'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().to_frame('Aggregated Alliance Products')

db[["A","B"]].merge(k, left_on=db.index.get_level_values(0), right_on=k.index.get_level_values(0)).drop('key_0', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   Aggregated Alliance Products
0   1   2   1
1   1   2   2
2   1   2   4
3   3   4   5
4   3   4   6
```